# How learn about TightVNC on a Pi

Tags: remote

I am a complete novice about and am using the first pi model made. Also I know nothing about TightVNC. Right now my pi is cabled to my router. It has keyboard, mouse and a HD tv. I down loaded Noobs and automatically update to Jesse per recommendations. I am trying to make the pi headless so I can do everything on a MacBook Pro. My long term goal is to use and control a hobby robot (to be built). Using the pi's terminal I've tried to install TightVNC but got an error message saying it doesn't know where to put it.

So can someone recommend a reading list or a book for dummies about tightVNC on a pi. Some explanations of what has to go where and why?

Comment: What was the error message exactly? what OS are you running? What version of the OS? How did you try to install it - what command(s) did you use? This would be  a good place to start https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-7-remote-control-with-vnc/overview assuming you are running Raspbian?

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I learned! (Recently, too...so it still works!)

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md

Answer (score -2):

Here's quite good tutorial how to setup TightVNC

http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server#Instructions

Comment: That tutorial is obsolete. Search this site for current instructions.